# Returning nil array in python

Tags: python, arrays

I am solving a problem which inputs array of binary numbers and output should something like

> ["White", "Red"]

It returns an array of color.

Right now I have total two problems.
1. In `for rgb_code in hexcodes_array:`, it is supposed to iterate twice because I am inputting two numbers but it is only iterating the last item right now.

2. `for rgb_code in hexcodes_array:` is just returning a nil array right now when I checked it is returning a value from if statements.

My codes are like below:

```
def extract_number(number):
    number_in_string = str(number)
    red = number_in_string[:8]
    green = number_in_string[8:16]
    blue = number_in_string[16:24]
    return [int(red, 2), int(green, 2), int(blue, 2)]


def ambiguity_identifier(number, array):
    for item in array:
        count = 0
        if item == number:
            count = count + 1
    return count


def ClosestColor(hexcodes):
    array = []
    for item in hexcodes:
        hexcodes_array = []
        hexcodes_array.append(extract_number(item))

    for rgb_code in hexcodes_array:
        print(rgb_code)
        distance_black = ((rgb_code[0] - 0)**2 + (rgb_code[1] - 0)**2 + (rgb_code[2] - 0)**2)
        distance_white = ((rgb_code[0] - 255)**2 + (rgb_code[1] - 255)**2 + (rgb_code[2] - 255)**2)
        distance_red = ((rgb_code[0] - 255)**2 + (rgb_code[1] - 0)**2 + (rgb_code[2] - 0)**2)
        distance_green = ((rgb_code[0] - 0)**2 + (rgb_code[1] - 255)**2 + (rgb_code[2] - 0)**2)
        distance_blue = ((rgb_code[0] - 0)**2 + (rgb_code[1] - 0)**2 + (rgb_code[2] - 255)**2)
        distance_array = [distance_black, distance_blue, distance_green, distance_red, distance_white]
        lowest_number = min(distance_array)
        if ambiguity_identifier(lowest_number, distance_array) > 1:
            array.append("Ambiguous")
        elif distance_black == lowest_number:
            array.append("Black")
        elif distance_white == lowest_number:
            array.append("White")
        elif distance_red == lowest_number:
            array.append("Red")
        elif distance_green == lowest_number:
            array.append("Green")
        elif distance_blue == lowest_number:
            array.append("Blue")
    return array



if __name__ == '__main__':
    ClosestColor([101111010110011011100100, 110000010101011111101111])
```

Can I get any advices on this?
Thanks

Comment: `for item in hexcodes:` that loop is weird

Comment: also, simply run step by step and you'll quickly see why your function can only return 1 item

Comment: You reset your `hexcodes_array` each time in the loop. Also, your representation of colors as decimal numbers containing only 0s or 1s is _extremely_ strange; why not just as binary literals (`0b101...`), binary strings `'101'` or as normal hex colors (`#ff0000`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the reason you are only getting the last item in your array is clear:

```
for item in hexcodes:
    hexcodes_array = []
    hexcodes_array.append(extract_number(item))
```

You are resetting `hexcodes_array` to an empty list *inside the loop.* So naturally the only one left when the loop exits will be the last one.

To avoid this, don't do that.